# JSON request sample or JSON request example

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can I call this snippet of code an example, or should I call it a sample or both will work?

JSON request sample:

```
{
  "mac": "10:B5:S3:06:C6:E9",
  "route":0,
  "latitude":73.834588, 
  "longitude":60.704048,  

}
```

Comment: Do you mean "Can I call this snippet of code an **example**, or should I call it a **sample**?

Comment: @CopperKettle: Yes I meant as u wrote.

Answer (score 1):

If the context is part of an instruction or lesson on code snippets, I would use [***example***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/example):

> 3) a person or thing to be imitated; model; pattern; precedent
>   4) a problem, as in mathematics, designed to illustrate a principle or method

But if I asked "What is a code snippet?" you could show me and reply either way:

> This is a **sample** code snippet.
>   This is a **an example of** a code snippet.

Here it is an illustration or typical instance.

Answer (score 1):

A *sample* describes something taken from or captured from reality or a bigger picture, e.g. the code exists in production or "real life."

An *example* can be contrived and not exist in reality, and may not work in reality.

Samples can be examples, but not the other way around.

Comment: The definition I like for sample is a small part intended to show the quality, style, or nature of the whole - I like your qualification of something captured from reality. An example to me is something that is more carefully  constructed with the intention of educating someone or illustrating a point.

Answer (score 0):

You could say "Example of a JSON request".  In documentation, where brevity is prized, "JSON request example" or "Example JSON request" would also be acceptable.